# Approximation of Sum of Partial Harmonic series with only odd terms with elementary methods

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, approximation, harmonic-numbers

> Let $a=\frac{1^2}{1}+\frac{2^2}{3}+\frac{3^2}{5}…+\frac{1001^2}{2001}$ and $b=\frac{1^2}{3}+\frac{2^2}{5}+\frac{3^2}{7}…+\frac{1001^2}{2003}$ Find the closest integer to $a-b$

Using the identity $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, it was trivial to see that the above expression was equal to $$1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}…+\frac{1}{2001}-\frac{1001^2}{2003}$$

I know that the approximation for the summation of a Harmonic series till $n$ terms is $\ln(n)<S_{n}<\ln(n)+1$ but I couldn't figure out how to use that to arrive at an approximation of the above expression.

**EDIT:** I just made a really dumb mistake which somehow I didn't notice before posting. The expression I have written is wrong, @cosmo5 has corrected it in his answer. Nevertheless, I would still like to know how to approximate a Partial Harmonic Series, so I'm leaving my post as is

PS- Questions on Harmonic series always have answers that use advanced math, and I don't know any of that so I would request you to refrain from using it. I just want an approximation with an error margin of $≤1$ which the elementary methods should be good enough for

Comment: Please see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: Also the section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation).

Comment: I edited my answer adding the approximation you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum _{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{k^2}{2 k-1}-\frac{k^2}{2 k+1}\right)=\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{2 k^2}{4 k^2-1}=\frac{n^2+n}{2 n+1}$$
for $n=1001$ the difference is $500.75$

The answer is $501$

For the approximation of the partial harmonic numbers sum, I got
$$\sum _{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2 k-1}\approx\frac{1}{2} (\log (n)+\gamma +2 \log (2))$$

Where $\gamma\approx 0.5772156649$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.
It works great, because for $n=10000$ I got an error less than $10^9$.

Edit

Adding a term to the expansion at $\infty$ of the actual sum we have much more precision
$$\sum _{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2 k-1}\approx \frac{1}{48} \left(\frac{1}{n^2}+24 (\log (4 n)+\gamma )\right)$$
For $n=100$ I got an error less than $10^{10}$.

Comment: Thanks, may I ask how we arrive $\frac{1}{2} (\log (n)+\gamma +2 \log (2))$? I only knew that approximation of a normal harmonic series is $\log (n) +\gamma$. How did we get from there to this for a series with only odd terms?

Comment: @l1mbo I approximated the sum $$\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2 k-1}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\gamma +\log (4)\right)$$ at $\infty$. If you add a term you get  much more precision $$\frac{1}{48 n^2}+\frac{1}{2} (\log (n)+\gamma +\log (4))$$ for $n>10000$ they are "virtually" the same. For $n=100$ I got an error less than $10^{11}$

Answer (score 1):

Without Harmonic series approximation,
$a-b=$

$$1^2 + \frac{2^2-1^2}{3} + \frac{3^2-2^2}{5} + \ldots + \frac{1001^2-1000^2}{2001} - \frac{1001^2}{2003}$$

$$=1 + (2-1) + (3-2) + \ldots + (1001-1000) -\frac{1001^2}{2003}$$

$$=1001 - \frac{1001^2}{2003}$$

$$=1001\cdot\frac{1002}{2003}$$

$$\approx \boxed{501}$$

Comment: I just made a hideously embarrassing mistake, when calculating the sum, I forgot to cancel the denominators lol; anyways I'll still keep the question up because finding the approximation for the partial sum is still an interesting question

Comment: Should I just accept your answer for this and ask a new question

Comment: sorry for the confusion, by elementary methods I meant a relatively simple way to approximate the harmonic series. Like for $n$ terms, $\ln(n)<S_{n}<\ln(n)+1$

Comment: @cosmo5 the result is 501 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bk%5E2%2F%282+k+-+1%29+-+k%5E2%2F%282+k+%2B+1%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+1%2C+1001%7D%5D

Comment: I made a sign error. Thanks for pointing it out!